# Get the Vendor and Product details of the Network Adapter

Tags: shell-script, command-line, network-interface

Is there any alternative to get the Network Adapter details such as `Product and Vendor names` of the network adapter?

Since I don't have lshw and lspci utilities installed in my machine and neither the privilege to install them.
And also tried exploring in `/sys/device/driver/module` directory and could not get the details which I was looking into.

Comment: What is stopping you from installing `lspci` for yourself?  If you have a compiler, than download the source tarball and if you don't, find a compatible binary version.

Comment: @JuliePelletier- The real problem comes when I have to run this script for gathering those data across the infrastructure I mean for a bigger radar.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have no way to install a tool like *lshw* or *lspci* to make your life easier, you could manually parse through the files under `/proc/bus/pci/` and it's sub-directories.